# JSON to hashmap with GSON

Tags: java, json, dictionary, hashmap, gson

I working on a project in Java and I want to put text in a HashMap using GSON,here is my JSON:

```
{
"someText": {
    "text1": "lorem ipsum",
    "text2": "ipsum lorem"
    }
}
```

and here a piece of my code:

```
private static class myTexts {
    private final Map<String, String> someText = new HashMap<String, String>();
}
```

---

```
myTexts t = this.gson.fromJson(myJsonFile, myTexts.class);
```

I have this error: `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: duplicate key: null`, I've tried to find what's wrong for a while, but I can't seem to find the problem :/

Comment: I've forgot "}" at the end. This is my real Json, I've just done copy & paste mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a closing `}` to

```
{
"someText": {
    "text1": "lorem ipsum",
    "text2": "ipsum lorem"
}}
 ^
```

thus making your JSON well formed, the following

```
myTexts t = new Gson().fromJson(myJsonFile, myTexts.class);
System.out.println(t.someText);
```

prints

```
{text1=lorem ipsum, text2=ipsum lorem}
```

which seems to be what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
public static Map<String, String> jsonToMap(String jsonString) {
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
}
```